# Adding Grouped Product in Bundle Products in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, bundled-product

Can I add a grouped product into a bundled product in Magento 2.1? Is it possible?

Comment: tell me anyone.

Comment: It's impossible. But you can add all child products of grouped product to bundled product as bundle options

Comment: @LovelySetia did you find any solution to this?
any work around?